# Newline required at end of file but not found on using React Native

Tags: react-native

I can compile it succeed but it show the error message `Newline required at end of file but not found` under `;`

Why ?  It's because that i don't use a class or what ?

I'm confused with it , some one can tell me why , thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Also please don't post code as image. No one want to copy code from your image.

Comment: I got it , thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because of Eslint.
Either do it(put the new line after AppRegistry's line), or put this at the top of the file

```
/* eslint-disable eol-last */
```

This will force eslint to stop warning you. But just for 'eol-last' rule.

Comment: Or just insert a new line to the end. I think there is some reason for doing it, just do some research, maybe this will help you understand it better. https://evanhahn.com/newline-necessary-at-the-end-of-javascript-files/